# What causes a verb to be infinitive only?

Tags: verbs, infinitives, defective-verbs

Why are some verbs only usable in the infinitive? The one example I can think of is "to spite" (see "to wit in the accepted answer). While wiktionary claims that spited is a word, that doesn't match other ite words, like bite or smite. OED disagrees, saying there is no past tense.

Comment: It can be used as a noun of course, but I checked dictionaries. No past tense. I can't imaging that I would spit (to bite), spote (to smite), or spited (to slight) someone.
I checked: http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/spite and another.

Comment: hm. Wiktionary claims spited is a word. I don't know if I buy that. I can't smited or bited...

Comment: If the Oxford dictionaries list no past tense, that means it's regular. if there were actually no past tense, they would have noted this, the way they do for [must](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/must?q=must). The past tense is "I spited". It is rarely used.

Comment: @Jasper: good catch. That seems to be true currently, but it wasn't always true. From Shakespeare, *Romeo and Juliet:* "Beguiled, divorced, wronged, spited, slain"; *Much Ado about Nothing:* "If you spite it for my sake, I will spite it for yours; for I will never love that which my friend hates."

Comment: Are you sure you mean the OED and not some other Oxford dictionary? The online OED has citations showing *spited* used both as past tense and past participle.

Comment: @Lawton: smote and bit are the past tenses of smite and bite, respectively.

Comment: @Matt I know that. I was pointing out that if to spite was conjugated in the same way it would be spit or spote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is at least one verb in modern English that is only used in the infinitive; namely [to wit](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wit--2?q=to+wit#wit--2__2). What happened there was that *wit* used to be a normal verb (conjugated *I wot, I wist, I have wist*), but all uses except the infinitive *to wit* dropped out of use.

The same thing seems to be happening to the verb *spite*. For the verb *spite,* all uses except the infinitive are quite rare in modern English, and it is conceivable they will vanish completely relatively soon. It appears that in Shakespeare's time, the use of *spite* was not restricted to the infinitive:

> And that which spites me more than all these wants,
>     He does it under name of perfect love;  — *Taming of the Shrew,* Shakespeare.

Searching Shakespeare, it looks like he uses *spite* in the infinitive 4 times, and in other conjugations 3 times.

Comment: What about *I wist not that he was the high priest*?

Comment: That's the past tense: *I didn't know that he was the high priest.*

Comment: Er, yes. So not the infinitive, then.

Comment: But that was also written 400 years ago, before *wit* was an infinitive-only verb. I see I should have said *contemporary English* rather than *modern English*.

Comment: It is interesting that "unwitting" is still in use, but not "witting".

Comment: @Lawton: have you not come across *acting wittingly*?

Comment: Only as a negative unwittingly, which is certainly odd. As in, "He was my unwitting pawn", followed by "No, he was acting quite wittingly." I haven't really seen it used without an unwitting close at hand.

Answer (score 3):

My OED (2nd ed, 1989) does not say *spite* as a verb can only be used in the infinitive, nor does it say it has no past tense. When the past tense isn't specifically listed, it is regular. Many example quotes give *spited* as the past tense and part participle.

There is one sense of the verb *spite* that's limited to the phrase *to spite (one)*, i.e. in the infinitive. Here, it has a specific meaning; it is transitive, taking a person as object. However, there are other senses too. The infinitive isn't the only possible usage.

Learner's dictionaries like OALD and LDOCE tend to have limited senses or usages for certain words, showing learners only the most common usages, just like they only list a subset of the vocabulary as headwords and limit the definition words to 2000.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, rhyming words are *not* a reliable test. See [Wikipedia: English irregular verbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_irregular_verbs)

And, for that matter, if its bite/bit and smite/smote, then what exactly does that say about "spite" anyway? That we should pick a random vowel? :)